# Creating a custom toolbox icon for my custom user control

Tags: c#, bitmap, user-controls

I have been working at this a while but can't seem to figure it out!

I have a Solution that looks like the following layout...

```
Solution 'Gen' (2 projects)
'-> MyControls
    '-> graphics
        '-> UserControl1.bmp
    '-> UserControl1.cs
'-> Gen
    '-> MainGUI.cs
```

I want to simply make a toolbox icon so that I can see a nice icon on my toolbar instead of the blue-like gear (the default toolbox icon).

---

The steps I have currently taken...

**1. Created A Bitmap Image:**

I made a 16x16 pixel image that is 16 colors (4 bit).

**2. Embed The Image As A Resource:**

Clicked on the image in the Solution Explorer window, then in the properties window I changed the Build Action to "Embedded Resource".

**3. Add An Internal Class Used To Fix A Bug In The GetImageFromResource() Method:**

BEFORE the namespace declare I added the following lines...

```
internal class resfinder
{
}
```

**4. Add The Class Property 'ToolboxBitmap':**

Above the class declaration...

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
```

I added the following line...

```
[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(resfinder), "Gen.graphics.UserControl1.bmp")]
```

**5. Build Project:**

Under the Build menu I used "Rebuild Solution".

**ENTIRE BLOCK OF CODE:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

internal class resfinder
{
}

namespace Gen
{
    [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(resfinder), "Gen.graphics.UserControl1.bmp")]
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

---

RESULTS:

I still have the little blue-like gear as a toolbox icon when I try to use it on the MainGUI.cs form.

---

Sources:

- [How to find the elusive ToolboxBitmap icon](https://web.archive.org/web/20120804065638/http://www.bobpowell.net/toolboxbitmap.htm)
- [How to: Provide a Toolbox Bitmap for a Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-provide-a-toolbox-bitmap-for-a-control)
- [Displaying custom icon for custom control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742781/displaying-custom-icon-for-custom-control)

Answer (score 3):

It seems the answer is simple...  I have actually done everything right!

There is a small thing worth noting though...

> The custom toolbox icon will NOT show up if you are using a reference
>   to a project in the same solution.

To fix/workaround this you need to do the following...

> Add a reference to the compiled (product of the custom control
>   project) DLL file instead.

I ended up removing the custom control project after compiling it and then adding a reference to my project that I wanted to use it on.  After I did that I right clicked in the Toolbox then clicked "Choose Items...".  Then clicked Browse and loaded the DLL from there.

Now the custom toolbox icon shows up just fine!